# how to set current Date as MinDate in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, calendar, datepickerdialog

I have one activity that i use to create customer, in this activity i have one edit text that can show the current date when user open screen. its can be change to future date but not past date so i have used

```
d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

to set current date as a minimum date and `onClick` i have opening `DatePickerDialog`. But, when click on that edit text app is crashed and this error show in `Logcat`.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Wed Aug 22 16:31:24
>   GMT+05:30 2018 does not precede toDate: Wed Aug 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30
>   2018

here is my edittext `onClickListner` code.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormatForDOB);
try {
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(edt.getText().toString()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

DatePickerDialog d2 = new DatePickerDialog(CreateUpdateOpportunityActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth,
     new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int years,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    year = years;
                    month = monthOfYear;
                    day = dayOfMonth;
                    tv.setText(DateUtil.getDateOfBirth(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day));
                }
            }, year, month, day);

d2.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
d2.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
d2.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
d2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
d2.show();
d2.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

i used other solution like

```
d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

or

```
d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 10000);
```

but still app crash and same error comes

if i comment above line of code, my app run without crash.

Comment: what is DateUtil.dateFormatForDOB?

Comment: as default set when user open screen...i get current date and set directly in edittext...
that is that cureent date format
 public static final String dateFormatForDOB = "MM/dd/yyyy";

Comment: @MayurKarmur, try this code  and check if (cal.getTimeInMillis() > System.currentTimeMillis()){
            d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        }

Comment: thanks...and what about in else part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if calendar date(cal.getTimeInMillis())  is greeter then your current date(System.currentTimeMillis())

like this

```
 if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Current time is big",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    } else {
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Current time is small",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        d2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

may be this help